# No route to host: physical connection doesn't work (but from a VM yes)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, route

I use Ubuntu Desktop v. 22.04 and at the work there is a very-complicated LAN, with different subnets.

Long story made short, until to some day ago I did could connect to a website hosted on IP

192.168.103.31 (my fixed IP is 10.3.0.205). Yes, it worked like a charm.

From some day, I can connect to that website ONLY or using a VPN or, for example, with a bridged connection on a VM (!).

I did try:

1. Another IP from other collegue
2. Using other cable (!)
3. Placing PC of a collegue to my desk (his PC works)

I know that seems impossible, but is there some possibility that I can check something?

This is the `route` command output

```bash
Tabella di routing IP del kernel
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
10.3.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
10.200.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-69b1f6365454
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-f866652e0985
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e8c926073f48
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-b73dc74c8e81
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-7ce9f550276a
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e456c467c786
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-97322a01398b
172.25.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e93c251992dc
172.26.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-693855b1ce58
172.27.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-2cc3e1f53fe2
172.28.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-4f52aeb07eb5
172.29.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-4d2807740de0
172.30.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-1cd9d603111f
172.31.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-06e8b2cd824b
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-0e0a036a5318
192.168.16.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-4fef4a9909ae
192.168.32.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-90f143fce7fe
192.168.48.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-8bbf2e751105
192.168.64.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-5781c4b32352
192.168.80.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-13d702f3f169
192.168.96.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-871be59076d8
192.168.112.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-25eba4fd1c90
192.168.128.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-9ca47d7eef50
```

(that br- are docker related)

sys-admin says there is no block on router / firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the site you want to access on 192.168.103.31 is on a server, not in a docker container.

There is a route with a conflicting subnet:

```
192.168.96.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-871be59076d8
```

The route to 192.168.96.0 with the subnet-mask 255.255.240.0 will route everything from 192.168.96.1 - 192.168.111.254 to the interface br-871be59076d8. (Including requests to 192.168.103.31)

To test if that route is indeed the source of your problem, you can use the ip command to delete the route:

```
sudo ip route del 192.168.96.0 dev br-871be59076d8
```

You can then try to access the website on 192.168.103.31. If that works, make sure to disable the docker network configuration that specifies that route.

Comment: How do you "disable the docker network configuration that specifies that route"?

Comment: List the docker networks that are present with ```docker network ls``` and then remove it with ```docker network rm```. 

[This](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_ls/) and [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_rm/) document this quite well. 

You should also check your docker compose file for network configs that might cause the issue [See here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)